# Polymer build with custom babel plugins?

Tags: babeljs, polymer-3.x, polymer-cli

We'd like to be able to add custom functionality to `polymer build` and `polymer serve` by configuring custom babel plugins.

For example, since polymer-cli uses babel internally, we would add a `babel.config.js` file to our workspace/project-root, e.g.:

```
module.exports = function (api) {

  api.cache(true);


  const presets = [ ];
  const plugins = [
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
 ];


  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

...and then we could serve or build our project with support for optional-chaining, etc This would allow us to do all sorts of things by writing additional babel plugins to handle stuff like minification inside template HTML strings...

Unfortunately, this doesn't currently work. `polymer-build` seems to load the configuration (due to its use of babel/core?), but `polymer-analyze` doesn't. An error is generated in the build-optimization step performed by polymer-analyze as soon as it encounters optional-chaining syntax in our source:

```
error:  Error: Unable to get document file:///.../somefile.js: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin:  
'optionalChaining' (423:6)  
    at BuildAnalyzer.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:342:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)  
    at fulfilled  (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/polymer-build/lib/analyzer.js:17:58)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

`polymer serve` also generates an error:

```
Error { SyntaxError: This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'optionalChaining' (423:6)
    at Parser.raise (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:776:15)  
    at Parser.expectPlugin (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2084:18)  
...   
pos: 13056,   loc: Position { line: 423, column: 6 },  
missingPlugin: [ 'optionalChaining' ] }
```

In both cases, I've confirmed that the `babel.config.js` file **is** being loaded. But babel is included by several different packages used in polymer-cli, so my suspicion is that in some of them, babel is being used without (babel/core having loaded) configuration info.

Can anyone involved with the polymer project confirm whether I'm correct in identifying the main issue? I'm looking into the possibility of contributing a fix/enhancement if the scope isn't too large.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you need to write your own custom build. Polymer-cli will provide its tool also for this. Have a look at this example:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/generator-polymer-init-custom-build

Answer (score 0):

For us, this issue was preventing us from using modern JS language features (like optional chaining and the nullish coalescing operator) which have wide support in modern browsers.

The only solution we could come up with was [forking](https://github.com/KatapultDevelopment/tools/tree/serve-es-next) the Polymer `tools` monorepo and adding in support for the appropriate Babel plugins ourselves.

---

The file in question is `/packages/build/src/js-transform.ts`. Both `serve` and `build` use this file for Babel transforms. We switched to using Rollup for our build process, but we still needed a development server and couldn't get any others to work, so we forked the repo and built our own version of the standalone `polyserve` package. Would love to some day switch to Modern Web's [`@web/dev-server`](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/overview/).